# Deleted partition

Tags: 14.04, data-recovery

I switched from Windows 8 to Ubuntu 14.04, there were three (3) partitions, one with Windows and the other two with personal data. Now I have a single partition of 500GB. kindly help me to recover partitions and data.

Comment: i am not having any other drive to save the data will it be possible on same drive, is there any issue about overwriting like stuff? @karel

Comment: No, you will have to attach another drive for recovery otherwise there is a high risk your data are lost forever. Also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu